# Why two completely different strings are seen as equal by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In my sql server this:

```
select case when  N'ܐܪܡܝܐ' = N'አማርኛ' then 1 else 0 end
```

produces `1`. I could reproduce this [here](http://rextester.com/IAVT39994) as well. Can anybody explain to me why?

Comment: Which collation is used in the database?

Comment: @John Saunders SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. But these are two different strings, shouldn't that always return 0, despite collation?

Comment: [To quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx): _"Objects that use nchar or nvarchar are assigned the default collation of the database unless a specific collation is assigned using the COLLATE clause"_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specific collation need not contain sorting information for every code point defined in Unicode.

If you only need to test for (binary) equality of strings, ignoring every sort order, use the Latin1_General_BIN collation (or any [other collation ending in _BIN or _BIN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx)):

```
select case 
    when N'ܐܪܡܝܐ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = N'አማርኛ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
    then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, so I add another answer, referring to @JBrooks' answer:

What's going on if you execute

```
select ascii('ܐ') AA, ascii('አ') AB
```

Well first, the string literals, which are Unicode code points above the ASCII range, are converted to '?' because they are not marked as Unicode strings (`N''`).

Then, the function ASCII is executed on the non-Unicode string '?', which obviously results in 63.

So let's just add the Unicode string marker `N''`:

```
select ascii(N'ܐ') AA, ascii(N'አ') AB
```

Again, the result is 63 for both expressions, but by a different route: while strings are declared as Unicode, the ASCII() function treats its argument as Non-Unicode strings, leading to the result 63.

The get the actual code point of the two Unicode characters, you need to apply the UNICODE() function:

```
select unicode(N'ܐ') AA, unicode(N'አ') AB
```

which correctly results in 1808 and 4768.

Final question: Why a question mark?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark)

> The question mark character is also often used in place of missing or
>   unknown data. In Unicode, it is encoded at U+003F ? question mark
>   (HTML: ?).

and, further down in the article

> In many web browsers and other computer programs, "?" is used to show
>   a character not found in the program's character set. [...] Some fonts
>   will instead use the Unicode Replacement Glyph (U+FFFD, �), which is
>   commonly rendered as a white question mark in a black diamond (see
>   replacement character).

So the '?' question mark can be seen as the ASCII equivalent of the [Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Specials#Replacement_character), which itself cannot be expressed by an ASCII value.

Comment: Thanks, I would also add that to convert back to character from code one should use char for ascii and nchar for unicode

Answer (score 0):

If I run this they both come back with 63.

```
select ascii('ܐ') AA, ascii('አ') AB
```

Comment: In fact any character from those two words return 63, and char(63)  [produces](http://rextester.com/GWDD65561) '?'. Pretty unintuitive, but I guess when this decision was made (like 20 years ago:) ) it was OK.

Comment: please my second answer regarding the "mysterious" question mark.